# How to copy a file then save the destination path to CSV

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, export-to-csv

I'm trying to copy a batch of files (those whose filename begins with 6 digits) from a temp folder to a permanent location, excluding those that already exist in the new location.

Once the copy is done, I want to export the filename and new path of the copied file into a CSV.

It's pretty easy to get the old file location and export to CSV, I'm just not quite sure how to get the new file location.

My script looks like this:

```
# Prompt for file origin
$file_location = Read-Host -Prompt "Where do you want your files to come from?"
# Prompt for file destination 
$file_destination = Read-Host -Prompt "Where do you want your files to go? `n(They won't be copied if they're already there)"

# Save contents of file destination - used to check for duplicates
$dest_contents = Get-ChildItem $file_destination

<# For all of the files of interest (those whose names begin with 6 digits) in $file_location, 
     determine whether that filename already exists in the target directory ($file_destination)
     If it doesn't, copy the file to the destination
     Then save the filename and the new** filepath to a CSV #>

Get-ChildItem -Path $file_location |      
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^\d{6}' -And !($dest_contents -Match $_.Name ) } |
    Copy-Item -Destination $file_destination -PassThru | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, FullName |             # **Note: This saves the old filepath, not the new one
    Export-CSV -Path "$file_location\files_copied.csv" -NoClobber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I'd use a different approach testing if destination exist while iterating source files.
- To append to a present csv (log) file you need to remove the header of the new one.
- As Get-ChildItem allows ranges [0-9] you can directly select leading numbers

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\08\08\SO_51738853.ps1
# Prompt for file origin
$SrcDir = Read-Host -Prompt "Where do you want your files to come from?"

# Prompt for file destination 
$DstDir = Read-Host -Prompt "Where do you want your files to go? `n(They won't be copied if they're already there)"

$SrcFiles = Join-Path (Get-Item $SrcDir).Fullname [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*

$CopiedFiles = ForEach ($SrcFile in (Get-ChildItem -Path $SrcFiles)){
    $DstFile = Join-Path $DstDir $SrcFile.Name
    If (!(Test-Path $DstFile)){
        $SrcFile | Copy-Item  -Destination $DstFile -PassThru | 
            Select-Object -Property Name, FullName
    }
}    

# Check if log file exists, if yes append, otherwise export.
$LogFile = Join-Path $SrcDir "files_copied.csv"
If ($CopiedFiles){
    If (!(Test-Path $LogFile)){
        Export-CSV -Path $LogFile -InputObject $CopiedFiles -NoTypeInformation
    } else {
        # We need to remove the Header appending to the present csv
        $CopiedFiles | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Add-Content -Path $LogFile
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also fantastic! The solution Theo suggested results in a minimal change to the original code, with the precise answer to the question.

But this solution allows appending to the log file, rather than creating new files for each copy. That was next on my to-do list!

Comment: Although, the `Export-CSV` cmdlet outputs a summary of the copy rather than the filenames to the log file when you use `-InputObject`. The else statement appends the existing CSV appropriately, so I've changed that pipeline from:
`Export-CSV -Path $LogFile -InputObject $CopiedFiles -NoTypeInformation`
to:

`$CopiedFiles | Export-CSV -Path $LogFile`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a few changes to the code

```
# Prompt for file origin
$file_location = Read-Host -Prompt "Where do you want your files to come from?"
# Prompt for file destination 
$file_destination = Read-Host -Prompt "Where do you want your files to go? `n(They won't be copied if they're already there)"

# Save contents of file destination - used to check for duplicates
$dest_contents = Get-ChildItem $file_destination | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

<# For all of the files of interest (those whose names begin with 6 digits) in $file_location, 
     determine whether that filename already exists in the target directory ($file_destination)
     If it doesn't, copy the file to the destination
     Then save the filename and the new** filepath to a CSV #>

Get-ChildItem -Path $file_location |      
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^\d{6}' -and ($dest_contents -notcontains $_.Name ) } |
    ForEach-Object { 
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $file_destination 
        # emit a PSObject storing the Name and (destination) FullName of the file that has been copied
        # This will be used to generate the output in the 'files_copied.csv'
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{ Name = $_.Name; FullName = (Join-Path $file_destination $_.Name)})
    } | 
    Export-CSV -Path "$file_location\files_copied.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Note that i only gather the **Names** of the files already in the destination path instead of the fileInfo objects. This makes it a lot 'leaner' since the only reason for gathering is to have a collection of file names to compare with.

As it is now, you have a fixed name for the 'files_copied.csv' and personally i think it would be a good idea to make that more generic by adding the current date to it for instance like

```
Export-CSV -Path ("{0}\files_copied_{1}.csv" -f $file_location, (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")) -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

P.s. I'm using the `[ordered]` here so the output will always have the properties in the same order. This however requires PowerShell v3 or better.
Also, i suggest looking at the `-File` or `-Attributes` switches on the `Get-ChildItem` command if you need to make sure the code only copies Files, not Directories. If your version of PowerShell is 2.0, you can use the `Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }` construct to filter out files only.